# CSS gradient on text input

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make the text color of an `<input>` a gradient? I found this solution for static text but it does not work for input:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, rgb(66, 251, 227), rgb(43, 43, 
  255));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: it's working fine : https://jsfiddle.net/6bkgen21/2/

Comment: @TemaniAfif if you use the input the text is white

Comment: no, it works but onchange ... add the text and then move the mouse

Comment: @TemaniAfif You are right but it looks ugly on Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUAhk.gif. thefewunshaken in the worst case, you can "cover" the input with span that get its content from the input.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible please try this

```
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #f00 5%, #000 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #f00 5%, #000 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #f00 5%, #000 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #f00 5%, #000 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #f00 5%, #000 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.05, #f00),
    color-stop(1, #000)
);
```

Comment: somebody downvoted your work. Maybe because the answer is about background color and the question is about the foreground color?

Comment: This changes the background color of the input, not the text of the input.